# How to remove spaces between comma or numbers in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT REPLACE('10,6 7 7,900 11,027,900', ' ', '')
SELECT REPLACE('10,2 27,900 10,6 7 7,900 11,027,900', ' ', '')

Bad Result: 

    10,677,90011,027,900
    10,227,90010,677,90011,027,900

Good Result: 

    10,677,900 11,027,900
    10,227,900 10,677,900 11,027,900
```

Comment: What is the difference between "6 7 7" and "900 11"?

Comment: @Xiaosu 6 7 7 is 3 digits number in a million number separated by a comma at you can see while 900 11 is separated by of spaces actually those 2 numbers are in a single row in a table.

Comment: How do you know which space to remove?

Comment: @FelixPamittan between the comma only with 3 digits.

Comment: Can you provide more sample data and expected result.

Comment: @FelixPamittan I updated the sample above. Please see. Thank you.

Comment: On the 2nd sample, why does `2 27` became `227`? It's only two numbers.

Comment: it just remove the space between 2 27 so it became 227

Comment: Why though? `900 11` still has space.

Comment: the result 900 11 is not valid for 3 digits with a million number example 1,333,333 is valid 1,33333,333 is not valid

Comment: Very unclear message - while you have shown an example of what you want to see, it doesn't really help if we cannot understand the goal you're attempting to reach.

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd requirement. Before this goes downhill, I suggest you  normalize your table properly. Anyway, if you're stuck with what you have for now, here is a way to solve your problem.

First, you need a [string splitter](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), to split strings by comma. I use [`DelimitedSplit8K`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), written by Jeff Moden and improved by the members of SQL Server Central community.

After splitting the string, check if the value of each item after the space is removed has a length of 3. If yes, concatenate the new string *(space removed)*. Else, concatenate the original item.

```
WITH Tbl(OriginalString) AS(
    SELECT '10,6 7 7,900 11,027,900' UNION ALL
    SELECT '10,2 27,900 10,6 7 7,900 11,027,900'
),
TblSplitted(originalString, ItemNumber, Item) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Tbl t
    CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(t.OriginalString, ',')
)
SELECT *
FROM Tbl t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ',' +
            CASE 
                WHEN LEN(REPLACE(s.Item, ' ', '')) = 3 THEN REPLACE(s.Item, ' ', '')
                ELSE s.Item
            END         
        FROM TblSplitted s
        WHERE s.originalString = t.OriginalString
        ORDER BY s.ItemNumber
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
) x(NewString);
```

Comment: what is DelimitedSplit8K?

Comment: It's a string splitter. Click the link I provided. You can download the source code there.

Comment: thank you so much men, is there other way? example separated if encountered million digits 10,227,90010,677,90011,027,900 to 10,227,900 10,677,900 11,027,900